# How to set method of CURL to PUT?

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to set the http method of Curl to PUT but my code is not working

```
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: 
  application/json','Content-Length: ' . strlen($post)));
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PUT');
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
```

The above code is what I have written but it is not setting it to PUT method 
Please help

Comment: https://lornajane.net/posts/2009/putting-data-fields-with-php-curl

Comment: [Using CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS implies CURLOPT_POST.](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS.html)

Answer (score 1):

Try changing

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PUT');
```

to

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PUT');
```